# how to open page in new tab with response.redirect or response.write

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button event. At the end of the event I am redirecting to another page. But unable to open in new tab.

Giving compilation error -

> newline in constant

```
//Response.Redirect("DeliveryChallanPrint1.aspx?val=" +this.txtPoNo.Text);

Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('DeliveryChallanPrint1.aspx?val="+this.txtPoNo.Text','_blank')");//error - newline in constant
Response.Write("</script>");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

missing `+"`

```
 Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
 Response.Write("window.open('DeliveryChallanPrint1.aspx?val="+this.txtPoNo.Text+"','_blank');"); 
 Response.Write("</script>");
```

Comment: @krishnamohan yes may be pop up blocked it working fine for me

Comment: change firefox settings to allow popups

Comment: @krishnamohan mark it as answer if it worked for you